# In Cordova Android app, can you sample the accelerometer faster than 60 ms?

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

We are currently using the following code to record data at a rate of 20 ms..

watchID = navigator.accelerometer.watchAcceleration(onSuccess, onError, { frequency: 20 });

In the "onSuccess" function, we capture the data to file for inspection.  We, however, see that we're only capturing data points at a rate of 60 ms.

Is this a limit of the Android Cordova framework?

I'm testing my app on a Galaxy S3.

Answer (score 0):

Read [the docs](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/cordova-plugin-device-motion/index.html)

> Android Quirks
>
> The accelerometer is called with the SENSOR_DELAY_UI flag, which
>   limits the maximum readout frequency to something between 20 and 60
>   Hz, depending on the device. Values for period corresponding to higher
>   frequencies will result in duplicate samples. More details can be
>   found in the [Android API Guide](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_overview.html#sensors-monitor).

It's a limit on the device, not on cordova